# drawing straight line which passes through a point in between

Tags: php

I need to draw a straight line from Point A to point C, which has to pass through point B somewhere in between.

The problem is that I got coordinates of just A and B, not C. For point C I only has "x" coordinate.

Its like I have to draw a line from A to B, and extend it to C.

```
<?php
$im = imagecreate( 600, 600 );
$background= imagecolorallocate( $im, 25, 25, 75 );
imagefill( $im, 0,0, $background );
$white= imagecolorallocate( $im, 255, 255, 255 );

$a= array( 100, 200 );
$b= array( 200, 176 );
$c= array( 300, '' ); // This is to be calculated

imageline( $im, $a[0], $a[1], $c[0], $c[1], $white );

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); imagejpeg($im); exit();
?>
```

The straight line has to start at A, touch B, and end at C...  How do I calculate the "y" coord of point c?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The math for this is relatively simple. You can calculate the y-value of `c` as follows:

```
cy = ay + (by - ay) * (cx - ax) / (bx - ax)
```

This works by "extending" the y-value by the same ratio as we've extended the x-value. We *know* the ratio of the vector `a->c` to `a->b` since we have all three `x` values. We just need to apply that same ratio to the `y` values.

For your given data, that's:

```
                          ______________________
                         /  This is the ratio   \
                         |                      |
cy = ay  + (by  - ay)  * (cx  - ax)  / (bx  - ax)
   = 200 + (176 - 200) * (300 - 100) / (300 - 200)
   = 200 +    -24      *    200      /    100
   =                 152
```

Note that this won't work if the line is vertical (`a` and `b` share the same `x` value) since that results in division by zero. That's not fixable since it means `c` must also have the same x-value and therefore its y-value could be *anything.*

Comment: OMG! That is great. Thank you so much :)